# Simultaneously solving three nonlinear algebraic equations for two unknowns

Tags: equation-solving

The system I'm considering is:

```
eqn2 = 
  {wB/(kB*T) + Log[(σB*AP)/(1 - σB*AP)] == 
   Log[(CP - (CB*σB*At + CH*σH*At))*vP] == 
   wH/(kB*T) + Log[(σH*AP)/(1 - σH*AP)]}
```

I want to find `σB` and `σH` as functions of everything else and then find CP when these densities have a threshold value of `(P/L)*/al`. Using `Solve` doesn't work, and I need my solution to scale up to handling a similar system with four equations and three unknown densities `σB1, σB2` and `σH`. `wB, wH, AP, At` and `vP` are all known constants and `CP, CB` and `CH` are controlled variables. How would I proceed? `Solve` returns a blank list and I'm not sure how one would use `FindRoot` on this.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is a bit confusing. Can we rewrite it like this:

```
eqn1 = wB/(kB*T) + Log[(σB*AP)/(1 - σB*AP)];
eqn2 = Log[(CP - (CB*σB*At + CH*σH*At))*vP];
eqn3 = wH/(kB*T) + Log[(σH*AP)/(1 - σH*AP)];
Solve[{eqn1 == eqn2, eqn2 == eqn3}, {σH, σB}]
```

in which case it does solve for $\sigma$H and $\sigma$B, though the answer is ridiculously long.